# define a computed column reference another table

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, calculated-columns

I have two database tables, **Team** (`ID, NAME, CITY, BOSS, TOTALPLAYER`) and 
**Player** (`ID, NAME, TEAMID, AGE`), the relationship between the two tables is one to many, one team can have many players.

I want to know is there a way to define a `TOTALPLAYER` column in the `Team` table as computed?

For example, if there are 10 players' `TEAMID` is 1, then the row in `Team` table which `ID` is 1 has the `TOTALPLAYER` column with a value of 10. If I add a player, the `TOTALPLAYER` column's value goes up to 11, I needn't to explicitly assign value to it, let it generated by the database. Anyone know how to realize it?

Thx in advance.

BTW, the database is SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: What is wrong with calculating the value in a query on demand?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can do that - you need a function to count the players for the team, and use that in the computed column:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CountPlayers (@TeamID INT)
RETURNS INT 
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @PlayerCount INT

    SELECT @PlayerCount = COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Player WHERE TeamID = @TeamID

    RETURN @PlayerCount
END
```

and then define your computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Team
ADD TotalPlayers AS dbo.CountPlayers(ID)
```

Now if you select, that function is being called every time, for each team being selected. The value is not persisted in the **Team** table - it's calculated on the fly each time you select from the **Team** table.

Since it's value isn't persisted, the question really is: does it need to be a computed column on the table, or could you just use the stored function to compute the number of players, if needed?

Comment: Do you mean the function will execute everytime when I query a team out?

Comment: @HeroIverson3: yes - it will be executed on every SELECT to the table that includes that column (including for each `SELECT * FROM Team`)

Comment: Is there another way to realize it? I want the column only update when I add or delete a player. when I query a team out, only like query other tables, without the function execute. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Or, my design is not a proper method?

Comment: @HeroIverson3: to achieve an update only when something changes, you would need to have a trigger on the `Player` table. But that always has the risk of not working properly - in that case, I would probably just compute the number of players using the function (or an equivalent subselect) when needed.

Comment: @HeroIverson3: Seconding that. If you had a static updatable `TotalPlayers` column in `Team`, you would have to make sure that, for safety's sake, the column was never touched by any explicit `UPDATE` but the one in the trigger (and to ensure the initial `0`, you would probably need to specify a `DEFAULT` constraint and, again for safety, always omit the column in your `INSERT` statements).

Comment: @marc_s, thanks for your reply! Add a function is a good way to do that, or I needn't add such a column, only compute the total number in query by joining the two tables?

Comment: @Andriy M, thanks for your reply! Add a function is a good way to do that, or I needn't add such a column, only compute the total number in query by joining the two tables?

Comment: @HeroIverson3: Unless it was a huge database, I would go with a dynamically computed value. A static computed column in the table using a function like in marc_s's answer might do, but I would only use this approach if the tables were fairly small. Otherwise I would compute the value in my queries. A compromise solution might be to define a view based on a query along the lines of laser_dude's.

Comment: Is the `ID` in the `alter` statement from the `players` or from the `team` table?

Comment: @WairimuMurigi: since it's a computed column on the **`Team`** table, that `ID` also is from the `Team` table

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to store the total in the table -- it can be computed when you do a query, something like:

```
SELECT teams.*, COUNT(players.id) AS num_players
FROM teams LEFT JOIN  players ON teams.id = players.team_id
GROUP BY teams.id;
```

This will create an additional column "num_players" in the query, which will be a count of the number of players on each team, if any.

Comment: Basically yes, but this wouldn't compile in SQL Server, because the GROUP BY column list must include all the non-aggregated columns referenced in the SELECT clause.